# Jquery get cell data by Row and column Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get Cell data by Row and Column Id.

**Below is Example**

```
var columnId=2;
var rowId=1;
```

I need result `7.796`

```
var columnId=3;
var rowId=1;
```

I need result `"0.099"`

```
var columnId=6;
var rowId=2;
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom: 30px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <thead>
  <tr style="background-color:#E5E4E2;color:black">
     <th style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:20%;">Factor</th>
     <th class="factor_value" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;width:2%;">Factor Value</th>
     <th id="2_8" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Inverse Relationship</th>
     <th id="3_9" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Value 2</th>
     <th id="4_10" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Minimum Score</th>
     <th id="5_11" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Midpoint</th>
     <th id="6_12" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Slope</th>
     <th id="7_13" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Transformed Value</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
  <tr id="F_4">
     <td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Operating Margin (Operating Profit / Sales)</td>
     <td id="CH_245" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">7.796</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">No</td>
     <td class="formula_field fields" formula-coded="(@F_4º@FC_2º==&quot;@Noº&quot;,@CH_244º,@CH_244º*-1)" fieldtype="6" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;"></td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">No</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="1" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">0.099</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="1" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">26.182</td>
     <td class="formula_field fields" formula-coded="1+(1+EXP(-@F_4º@FC_6º*(@F_4º@FC_3º-@F_4º@FC_5º)))" fieldtype="6" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="F_6">
     <td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Cash Ratio (Cash to Current Liabilities)</td>
     <td id="CH_259" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">1.312</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">No</td>
     <td class="formula_field fields" formula-coded="(@8º====@11_Noº,@C_259º,@C_259º*-1)" fieldtype="6" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;"></td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">No</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="1" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">0.251</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="1" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">11.823</td>
     <td class="formula_field fields" formula-coded="1+(1/EXP(-@12º*(@9º-@11º)))" fieldtype="6" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;"></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think its better to say I tried to get instead of I want to get .. show us what you tried so far

Comment: Agree with @Mohamed-Yousef ... plus your examples are not according to what you want nor to the HTML code you provided.

Comment: @leo.fcx,if you checked the html i added id in <th> and also <tr> and also i am asking for column id not column index

Comment: @MuhammadRashid, all answers suggested similar solution ... meaning that your question is not clear.

Comment: @leo.fcx Yes i agreed with you and also others,i think i can not proper explain my question ,sorry for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```js
var row=2;//since the head takes a row too
var col1=2;
var col2=6;

console.log($('table tr').eq(row-1).find('td').eq(col1-1).text());
console.log($('table tr').eq(row-1).find('td').eq(col2-1).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom: 30px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <thead>
  <tr style="background-color:#E5E4E2;color:black">
     <th style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:20%;">Factor</th>
     <th class="factor_value" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;width:2%;">Factor Value</th>
     <th id="2_8" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Inverse Relationship</th>
     <th id="3_9" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Value 2</th>
     <th id="4_10" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Minimum Score</th>
     <th id="5_11" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Midpoint</th>
     <th id="6_12" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Slope</th>
     <th id="7_13" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Transformed Value</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
  <tr id="F_4">
     <td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Operating Margin (Operating Profit / Sales)</td>
     <td id="CH_245" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">7.796</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">No</td>
     <td class="formula_field fields" formula-coded="(@F_4º@FC_2º==&quot;@Noº&quot;,@CH_244º,@CH_244º*-1)" fieldtype="6" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;"></td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">No</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="1" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">0.099</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="1" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">26.182</td>
     <td class="formula_field fields" formula-coded="1+(1+EXP(-@F_4º@FC_6º*(@F_4º@FC_3º-@F_4º@FC_5º)))" fieldtype="6" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="F_6">
     <td style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">Cash Ratio (Cash to Current Liabilities)</td>
     <td id="CH_259" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">1.312</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">No</td>
     <td class="formula_field fields" formula-coded="(@8º====@11_Noº,@C_259º,@C_259º*-1)" fieldtype="6" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;"></td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="2" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">No</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="1" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">0.251</td>
     <td class="fields" fieldtype="1" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;">11.823</td>
     <td class="formula_field fields" formula-coded="1+(1/EXP(-@12º*(@9º-@11º)))" fieldtype="6" style="border:1px solid gray;text-align:left;color:black;padding:10px;  padding-top: 15px;min-width:3%;"></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to get cell text using b their id,if you look html then there is id on th and tr

Comment: only your rows and headers have ids, the columns (tds) don't seem to have ids

Answer (score 1):

Use `:nth()` and build the CSS selectors using your vars. See more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Following line should work for your code:

```
var row = 1;
var column = 2;
$('tbody tr:nth(' + row+ ')').find('td:nth(' + column + ')').text();
```

See [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5q6jt6k6/)

Comment: i want to get cell text using b their id,if you look html then there is id on th and tr

Comment: What? Your post did not mention anything about it. Elaborate your post first

Comment: but you are not getting by id ,you are getting row index

Answer (score 1):

For 1st row and 2nd column, try following selector

```
$("table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)")
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/LoeHl4dPpl9VRf1ywdwB?p=preview

You can now customize the above by passing parameters.

Comment: i want to get cell text using b their id,if you look html then there is id on th and tr

Comment: Your example's are not clear. Please explain a scenario again with more details.

Comment: Column id means <th> id and row id means <tr>

Comment: As per your markup, there is no `th` with id 2 and no `tr` with id 1.

Comment: Yes,but you are not getting by id ,you are getting row index

Comment: I agree. However, I want to know with which `th` will you co-relate your id as 2 and with which `tr` will you co-relate your id as 1 - in other words, explain in details about your examples as it makes no sense to me with current markup

Comment: if column id is 2 then  co-relate with id="2_8" ,actually id="2_8" is also co-relate with column id  8

Comment: Similarly if column id is 3 then co-relate with id="3_9" ,actually id="3_9" is also co-relate with column id 9 –